# Android app crashes the first time I try to copy a database from assets folder but it performs since then

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I have an odd problem, first time I run my app and try to copy a database from assets folder to it, it crashes but after that it is OK and database is copied, I really want to eliminate the first time crashes in my app. I've been searching for a while but I cannot find someone with same problem as me. Here is my class for copying a database from assets folder:

```
public  class holidaysDatabaseAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "holydays.sqlite";
    //public final static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/myPackage/databases/";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
    private final Context dbContext;

    public holidaysDatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.dbContext = context;
        //    DATABASE_NAME = "holydays.sqlite";
        // checking database and open it if exists
        if (checkDataBase()) {
            openDataBase();
        } else
        {
            try {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                copyDataBase();
                this.close();
                openDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "Initial database is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        InputStream myInput = dbContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        // String outFileName =dbContext.getDatabasePath("holidays.sqlite").toString();
        // DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(dbContext.getDatabasePath("holidays.sqlite"));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String dbPath = dbContext.getDatabasePath("holidays.sqlite").toString();
        dataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    }

    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        boolean exist = false;
        try {
            String dbPath = dbContext.getDatabasePath("holidays.sqlite").toString();
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.v("db log", "database does't exist :"+e.toString());
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            exist = true;
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return exist;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllProfiles() {

        Cursor mCursor = dataBase.query("ninety", new String[] {"_id","date","description"},  
                null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }}
```

And i instantiate that in my app like:

```
holidaysDatabaseAdapter db=new holidaysDatabaseAdapter(this);
```

And my LogCat is:

```
02-07 13:13:23.199: E/SQLiteLog(29509): (14) cannot open file at line 30046 of [9491ba7d73]
02-07 13:13:23.199: E/SQLiteLog(29509): (14) os_unix.c:30046: (2) open(/data/data/ir.nimbit.newcrm/databases/holidays.sqlite) - 
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509): Failed to open database '/data/data/ir.nimbit.newcrm/databases/holidays.sqlite'.
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at ir.nimbit.database.holidaysDatabaseAdapter.checkDataBase(holidaysDatabaseAdapter.java:79)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at ir.nimbit.database.holidaysDatabaseAdapter.<init>(holidaysDatabaseAdapter.java:35)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at ir.nimbit.newcrm.firstPage.onCreate(firstPage.java:95)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-07 13:13:23.202: E/SQLiteDatabase(29509):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-07 13:13:23.202: V/db log(29509): database does't exist :android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
02-07 13:13:23.264: D/AndroidRuntime(29509): Shutting down VM
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509): Process: ir.nimbit.newcrm, PID: 29509
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509): java.lang.Error: Error copying database
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at ir.nimbit.database.holidaysDatabaseAdapter.<init>(holidaysDatabaseAdapter.java:46)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at ir.nimbit.newcrm.firstPage.onCreate(firstPage.java:95)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-07 13:13:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(29509):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Please guide me.Thanks

Comment: please post the logcat of the crash.

Comment: @Henry I posted the logcat, please check it.

Comment: The real problem is hidden, because you swallow the IOException e before you throw the Error. But I guess it comes from this line `this.getReadableDatabase();`. I think you can remove it completely.

Comment: @Henry I did what you said but still I'm facing the problem.

Comment: Then log the exception before you throw the error and post the stack trace.

Comment: @Henry Problem solved, I did the tracing and I found there was a issue with InputStream myInput = dbContext.getAssets().open("DATABASE_NAME"); in CopyDataBase() so I changed the DATABASE_NAME to "holidays.sqlite" and problem solved although I have the same logcat now but at least my app is not crashing any more, thanks again.

Comment: I would recommend replacing all that code with `SQLiteAssetHelper`.